# The value of $\int_C \bar{z}dz$?

Tags: contour-integration

What is the value of $\int_C \bar{z}dz$ from $z=0$ to $z=4+2\pi i$ along the curve $C$ given by $z=t^2+it$?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate such integrals using curve parametrization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: parametrize it.

$$\bar{z}=t^2-it,~~~dz=(2t+i)dt$$

where $t$ is from $0$ to $2$

There should be a typo in your OP, from $z=0$ to $z=4+2i$

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome